# $\lim_{a\rightarrow 0} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+a\sin(x)} \, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Am I allowed to change limit and integral here? How can I solve this integral?

$$\lim_{a\rightarrow 0} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+a\sin(x)} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: consider a sequence of functions $f_n(x)=1/(1+\sin(x)/n)$. Is this sequence monotone wrt $n$? Where does it converge pointwise? Are $\int f_n$ finite?

Comment: the integrand converges "uniformly" to 1. in this case, it is legal to exchange the order of taking limit and integration.

Answer (score 2):

For $x\in[0,1]$ and $|a|<1/2$,
\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{1}{1+a\sin x}\right|\leq\dfrac{1}{1-(1/2)\sin(1)}
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{1-(1/2)\sin 1}dx<\infty,
\end{align*}
so it goes through by Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you chose $|a|<1/2$?

Comment: In some sense, yet, all I want to have is that $|1+a\sin x|\geq 1-|a||\sin x|>\eta>0$ for a constant $\eta$ which is independent of $a$. And we know that $|\sin x|\leq 1$, so $1-|a||\sin x|\geq 1-|a|$, and so if $|a|<1/2$, $1-|a|>1/2$. You may let $|a|<1/3$, but don't do for $|a|<1$.